# How to show the path structure of navigated pages in templates ( Site Map )

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

[image]How is it possible to show a page's path inside a page? My idea is to implement the path using a link just like the directory structure in the OS. How can I implement something like that?

> **You are Here:**
>
> Home > Category > Products > Shoes > Sports Shoes > Basketball > Nike

And these must be links so that when a user clicks on these, it opens the  following page.

[image]

Comment: Google "breadcrumbs" in html or or what ever cms or platform you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this code or download source code from url    https://mega.nz/#!UjR0iSbI!R2OUwlFtUePM7IvAGnQTBj17F8St-ZwjllSmPcR3pMc    and read the readme.md file**

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    w = "Home"
    context = {
        'ww': w,
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
def Category(request):
    w = "Category"
    context = {
        'ww': w,
    }
    return render(request, "Category.html", context)
def Products(request):
    w = "Products"
    context = {
        'ww': w,
    }
    return render(request, "Products.html", context)
def Shoes(request):
    w = "Shoes"
    context = {
        'ww': w,
    }
    return render(request, "Shoes.html", context)
def Sports_Shoes(request):
    w = "Sports Shoes"
    context = {
        'ww': w,
    }
    return render(request, "Sports_Shoes.html", context)
def Basketball(request):
    w = "Basketball"
    context = {
        'ww': w,
    }
    return render(request, "Basketball.html", context)
def Nike(request):
    w = "Nike"
    context = {
        'ww': w,
    }
    return render(request, "Nike.html", context)
```

**in templates dir create home.html , Category.html , Products.html , Shoes.html , Sports_Shoes.html , Basketball.html , Nike.html**

**Then paste the following code in all html pages and there is no need to change anything in the code**

```html
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/style.css" %}'>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ww}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id = "a1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/">Home </a>
<b id = "b1" > >>> </b>
<a id = "a1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Category">Category </a>
<b id = "b1" > >>> </b>
<a id = "a1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Products">Products </a>
<b id = "b1" > >>> </b>
<a id = "a1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Shoes">Shoes </a>
<b id = "b1" > >>> </b>
<a id = "a1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Sports_Shoes">Sports_Shoes </a>
<b id = "b1" > >>> </b>
<a id = "a1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Basketball">Basketball </a>
<b id = "b1" > >>> </b>
<a id = "a1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Nike">Nike </a>
<h1 id="welcome">{{ww}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**if you have other port change port 8000 frome html code**
**add on static > css > style.css and copy paste this code

```css
#welcome{
    font-size:200px;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
}

body{
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

**
**now add to urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('Category', views.Category, name='Category'),
    path('Products', views.Products, name='Products'),
    path('Shoes', views.Shoes, name='Shoes'),
    path('Sports_Shoes', views.Sports_Shoes, name='Sports_Shoes'),
    path('Basketball', views.Basketball, name='Basketball'),
    path('Nike', views.Nike, name='Nike'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it inside django template you can try [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-view-breadcrumbs/).